# How do I correctly assign graphics memory in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I've gone over to a Mac primarily for Garageband and logic. I'm not that competent with computers but was very happy to get VirtualBox adn Windows 7 up and running. I'm a bit stuck though in how to assign more graphics memory to it as it slows down when I open a few pages.

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: @KayJay: Updating VirtualBox does not affect your virtual machines.

Comment: Increasing the display memory will make things slower. More display memory means higher graphics detail at the expense of lower performance. Less display memory means less graphics detail in exchange for higher performance. (Although most likely in your case it will have no effect because it just won't use the additional memory.)